# Me tira el error array to string conversion cuando intento eliminar un registro Laravel Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

[image: Así tengo la vista donde tengo el boton de eliminar]

[image: Así lo tengo el metodo destroy en la carpeta livewire]

Ayúdenme por favor, no consigo el error.
public function destroy(Post $post){

```
    $post->delete();

    return view('welcome');

    //$this->emit('alert2', '¡Se elimino el post!');

}
```

Editar

```
            <x-jet-button wire:click="destroy({{$post->id}})">Eliminar</x-jet-button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el código como texto

Comment: Muestranos por favor de manera exacta el mensaje de error que obtienes

Comment: Yo creo que lo que quieres hacer es redirigir a la ruta que renderiza tu vista. Dónde esperas que livewire meta el retorno?